# How to detect call to methods from another form?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, delegates

I have a winform application that goes with name `myForm`. Within this form I open another form:

```
    private OtherForm otherForm; //this is a field

    private OpenOtherForm()
    {
       if (otherForm == null)
       {
          otherForm = new OtherForm();
          otherForm.FormClosing += delegate { MessageBox.Show("OtherForm will be closed"); otherForm = null};
       }

       MessageBox.Show("Form is already active!");
    }
```

This works fine. But I have some methods in the second form as well. I would like to try capturing theire call.

For example if OtherForm.DoSomething() is called within the second form, I want a message box to show thi.

I tried to assign `OtherForm.DoSomething() += delegate { /* mesagebox */};` But this does not compile

Comment: what is the error message you are getting when compiling..??

Comment: You did declare DoSomething as an event right?
Events don't have parentheses either, that could be the cause. Try `OtherForm.DoSomething += delegate { };` instead.

Comment: nah DoSomething is just a normal method which returns a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to respond to a call in another form you could add an event to the other form and raise it in the method you are trying to respond to.

```
class Form1: Form
{
    public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form2 = new Form2();
        form2.SomeMethodCalled += Form2_SomeMethodCalled;
    }

    public void Form2_SomeMethodCalled(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // method in form2 called
    }
}


class Form2 : Form
{
    public event EventHandler SomeMethodCalled;

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        OnSomeMethodCalled();
        // .....
    }

    private void OnSomeMethodCalled()
    {
        var s = SomeMethodCalled;
        if(s != null)
        {
            s(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`otherForm.FormClosing += delegate { .. }` is compiling because FormClosing is of type Event. An event can be subscribed to and when it's fired your code will run.

You can't use this syntax on a method like `DoSomething()`. A method can only be called with something like `otherForm.DoSomething()`. The code in `DoSomething()` will then be executed.

What you can do however is create your own event and fire it when DoSomething() is executed in the second form.

[Here is the MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w369ty8x.aspx) on publishing your own Event.

It would be something like:

```
public event EventHandler RaiseCustomEvent;

public void DoSomething()
{
    OnRaiseCustomEvent();
}

protected virtual void OnRaiseCustomEvent()
{
    EventHandler handler = RaiseCustomEvent;

    if (handler != null)
    {
         handler(this, EventArgs.Empty););
    }
}
```